# How Can I get the text of the selected radio in the radio groups

Tags: jquery, text, radio-button, checked

as said in the title
for example:

```
<input id="User_Type_0" type="radio" name="User_Type" value="1" checked="checked" />
<label for="User_Type_0">User1</label>
<input id="User_Type_1" type="radio" name="User_Type" value="2" />
<label for="User_Type_1">User2</label>
```

how can I get the text:User 1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<strike>$('input:radio:checked').siblings('label:first').html()</strike>

---

UPDATE:

As pointed out by Victor in the comments section the previous selector will always select the first label. The [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function should work:

```
$('input:radio:checked').next('label:first').html()
```

Comment: and if the order of the html-elements changes, you are screwed :-)

Comment: And this always selects the first label in DOM order, not the next one!!

Comment: @Victor, you are correct. Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

how about this?

```
var forLabel = $('input:radio:checked').attr("id");
$("label[for='" + forLabel + "']").text();
```

Comment: Good general idea, but you'll want to use a different variable name – `for` is a reserved word.

Comment: if there are more than 1 group, you can select which group you need with the `name`-attribute of the radiobutton

Answer (score 4):

use `.next();`

```
$("input:radio:checked").next().text();
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (I'm was using jQuery Mobile):

```
var value = $(":radio[name=location]:checked").val();
var text = $(":radio[name=location]:checked").prev("label").text();
```

The DOM for this:

```
<div id="locations" data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical ui-corner-all">
   <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
      <div class="ui-radio">
         <label for="location0" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-radio-off ui-first-child">1439</label>
         <input type="radio" name="location" id="location0" value="1439">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-radio">
         <label for="location1" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-radio-off ui-last-child">1440</label>
         <input type="radio" name="location" id="location1" value="1440">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using the next [Adjacent Selector, `+`](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/)?

```
$('input:radio:checked + label').text();
```

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ivufo)**