# get the value of input field of radio type in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, radio-button

I have an input field like below

```
<input class="d_o" type="radio" value="super" name="old_or_new" checked="checked"> Get this value actually</input><br/>
```

I have to get the value of the input field i.e., `Get this value actually`, so tried the below jquery code

```
console.log($('.d_o').text());
```

But i am surprised that its returning nothing, and its working when tried to get the value like `$('.d_o').val()`

So how to get the text value from the above input field using jquery am i missing anything ?

Comment: An `input` element isn't suppose to be closed. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

Comment: Try using the markup (and solution) of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132407/how-can-i-get-the-text-of-the-selected-radio-in-the-radio-groups

Answer (score 5):

The entirety of your `<input>` element is

```
<input class="d_o" type="radio" value="super" name="old_or_new" checked="checked">
```

The text that's after it, and the *invalid* html `</input>` are completely different nodes in the DOM tree. So `val` returns the value "super" as expected, but there's no text for `text` to return.

Comment: To add to this : W3C states to the specification : Content model:
Text for normal type of html element like <title> .. however for input types Content Model is empty .. Jquery might be following this.. Any validations on this fact ?

Comment: @user1428716 Yep, exactly--the `<input>` element can't contain any child elements or text nodes. Thanks for linking to the W3 spec!

Answer (score 1):

> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Although I am not sure what approach jQuery follows on this : One explanation can be the "Content Model" specification of each HTMLElement .

```
  Content model
  A normative description of what content must be included as children and descendants of the      element.
```

For example : 
For Input type : `http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element`

> Content model:Empty.

However for Title Element this is defined as

```
     Content model : Text 

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element
```

Eager to see the validations on this postulate :)

Answer (score 0):

`<input class="d_o" type="radio" value="super" name="old_or_new" checked="checked"> Get this value actually</input><br/>`

This is not the correct way to handle the `<input>` tag. You should use [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) and .[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hey').on('click', function(event){
        alert($('.check:checked').val());
    });
});
```

```
<h2>Select old or new</h2><br>

<b>Old</b>:<br>
<input type="radio" class="check" name="old_or_new" value="old"><br>

<br>

<b>New</b>:<br>
<input type="radio" class="check" name="old_or_new" value="new"><br>

<br>

<input type="button" id="hey">
```

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MLWCK/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, actually what all i need is to get the text `Get this value actually` after input tag, because i have many input tags as above like of radio type and a text after that. So i need to fetch the text after input tag and fill with another value at that place

Comment: K i agree and will modify the input tag as `<input type="radio" class="check" name="old_or_new" value="old">Get this value actually`, but like this i have many input tags, so need to fetch the text after every input radio type tag and change it with some other value ?